# Unable to set 2560x1440 resolution on new monitor

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi, lenovo-laptop

Recently bought a new monitor (Lenovo Q27-q10) and cannot get it to display at 2560x1440. When I go to change screen resolution, I'm only presented with up to 1920x1080. If I go into the intel graphics properties it still only shows up to 1920x1080 and if I try and set a custom resolution it says that it exceeds the maximum bandwith.

My setup is a lenovo ideapad 720s 141kb i5-8250u that has intel uhd620 graphics along with an mx150. I am running windows 10 and attempting to connect via supplied hdmi cable. In terms of troubleshooting, I have tried installing all the necessary drivers for the monitor and it hasn't helped.

Interestingly I plugged in via hdmi to my work laptop (lenovo t470s running windows 7!) and had no problem. Monitor displays at 2560x1440. So it seems like it's an issue with my laptop rather than the monitor itself.

Happy to supply any information as I realise I was quite brief here!

Many thanks in advance.

**Update:
Following the comments I purchased a usb-c/displayport cable to try out (my laptop had no displayport but had usb-c and the monitor had a displayport). It works perfectly now, displaying 2560x1440 at 7hz no problem!**

Comment: I cannot seem to find the monitor’s make and model in your question. Please [update your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1544934/edit) to contain it.

Comment: Updated now, sorry I forgot to include before!

Comment: Interesting. "Exceeds the maximum bandwith" sounds like a plausible explanation of the issue, but this iGPU should easily handle 1440p. Old HDMI version maybe...?

Comment: Chances are your laptop output is limited. If you have a DisplayPort output then you might be able to get a higher resolution via an adaptor, but these odd quirks are annoyingly common, especially for integrated or mixed graphics machines and particularly in the budget/midrange models.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I'll possibly try using adaptor as the monitor does have a DisplayPort output. Annoying really, I didn't realise these quirks were present. I just assumed that as it was a fairly recent model with thunderbolt 3 etc., that it would be modern enough to cope with 2560x1440.